# Power Query, Split Column Date and Time not Working

Tags: powerquery

Kindly to help me how to split column date and time, in the original file sources dd-mmm-yyyy (double space) hh:mm:ss
[image: xls sources data]

The problem is all the column extracted date only (I need the time also), please see the picture

[image: Query Result]

And here are the code

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("D:\IP_Enquiry_Result_20181015_082020.xls"), null, true),
    #"Enquiry Result1" = Source{[Name="Enquiry Result"]}[Data],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Enquiry Result1",{{"Column1", type text}, {"Column2", type text}, {"Column3", type text}, {"Column4", type text}, {"Column5", type text}, {"Column6", type text}, {"Column7", type text}, {"Column8", type text}, {"Column9", type text}, {"Column10", type text}, {"Column11", type text}, {"Column12", type text}, {"Column13", type text}, {"Column14", type text}, {"Column15", type text}, {"Column16", type text}, {"Column17", type text}, {"Column18", type text}, {"Column19", type text}, {"Column20", type text}, {"Column21", type text}, {"Column22", type text}, {"Column23", type text}, {"Column24", type text}, {"Column25", type text}, {"Column26", type text}, {"Column27", type text}, {"Column28", type text}, {"Column29", type text}, {"Column30", type text}, {"Column31", type text}, {"Column32", type text}, {"Column33", type text}, {"Column34", type text}, {"Column35", type text}, {"Column36", type text}, {"Column37", type text}, {"Column38", type text}, {"Column39", type text}, {"Column40", type text}, {"Column41", type text}, {"Column42", type text}, {"Column43", type text}, {"Column44", type text}, {"Column45", type text}, {"Column46", type text}, {"Column47", type text}, {"Column48", type text}, {"Column49", type text}, {"Column50", type text}, {"Column51", type text}, {"Column52", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Column47] <> null)),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Filtered Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true])
in
    #"Promoted Headers"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found the way to make it appear, it used microsoft query and everthing was fine.
I tried to use 'MS OLE DB Provider for ODBC driver' but the excel sources cannot be replaced.
Thank you everyone for your help, have nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that when you bring your spreadsheet's table into PowerQuery as the source, it will change the double-space between the date and time to a single-space. At least, that is what it did for me. Then, all you should need to do is select the column that has the Date and Time that you want to split and then click *Transform* > *Split Column* > *By Delimiter* > then change *--Custom--* to *Space* and click the radio button for *Left-most delimiter* and click OK.

Here's what the code ends up looking like (my table was named Table1 and the column was named DateTime):

```
let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"DateTime", type datetime}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"DateTime", type text}}, "en-US"), "DateTime", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({" "}, QuoteStyle.Csv, false), {"DateTime.1", "DateTime.2"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"DateTime.1", type date}, {"DateTime.2", type time}})
in
#"Changed Type1"
```

If it doesn't change your double-spaces to single-spaces when you bring your table in: instead of changing the *--Custom--* to *Space*, type two spaces (hit your space key twice) in the box below the *--Custom--*.

Comment: thank you for prompt response, I would like to confirm the method cannot shown the time :(

Comment: I don't know why it isn't working for you. It works fine for me. I set up the date in Excel as dd-mmm-yyyy (double space) hh:mm:ss and my code worked fine.